# Doctrine column type interval

Tags: doctrine-orm

Is it possible to set a column type as INTERVAL in doctrine?

```
CREATE TABLE periodicity (periodicity INTERVAL);
```

But with doctrine yml format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that I know of, but all doctrine "datetime" column types are internally created as PHP \DateTime Objects for you.

https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cookbook/working-with-datetime.html

Not entirely sure what your use case is, but if you wanted a timestamp (with an interval) on your entity you can simply mark a column as "new \Datetime('3 weeks')" in your construct function.

Comment: I want to be able in sql to add an interval to a date. eg : select start_date + periodicity * 5;

Comment: You can use DateTime objects in your DQL when selecting. "SELECT * FROM MyEntity WHERE date > :date"....   setParam('date', new DateTime('3 weeks'));